# Using Powershell to grab Registry Key data to build an If Else

Tags: powershell, key, registry

I am trying to use Powershell to check a particular registry key we use on servers in HKLM\SOFTWARE to identify their status as an Alpha, Beta or General server. I am not seeing an easy way to do this. I took a look at the Get-ItemProperty cmdlet, but that doesn't allow me to actually select the exact key within SOFTWARE that has the data I need to build out an If Else loop that can output the server type.

In its simplest form, I would like to use this Powershell script to read that key (to see if Alpha, Beta, General) and then depending on which, output simply Alpha, Beta or General as a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Get-Item?

```
$keyInfo = Get-Item -Path $Key 
#Where Key is something like hklm:\Software..

#This will give you all the subkeys to that key
$keyInfo.GetSubKeyNames() 

#This will give you data stored in the values of the key.
$keyInfo.GetValue($ValueName, $null, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
```